# Creating a Temporary Incrementing Number in an MS Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am writing a query which will return data that is needed for an export/import into a MySQL database. One of the required fields in the MySQL database is an id field. Currently, the data that I am trying to export does not have an id field but will need one for this export process.

Is there a way within the Access select query to make a number that increments for all the records that are in the result set (i.e., it starts at 1 and goes to 100 lets say if there are 100 records returned)?

Comment: Can you make the MySQL `id` field `auto_increment` type and let MySQL handle the numbering?

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think of this before! Feel free to add this as an answer and I'll give you the credit for it :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the MySQL `id` field [auto_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) type and let MySQL handle the numbering.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new AutoNumber field on that table in Access. You may have to create a new table. You can copy the existing table into a new table that includes an autonumber field. The instructions can be found here: [How to reset an AutoNumber field value in Access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812718)